# how to make a large image to be seen in full on the layout when writing android:scaleType="matrix" in XML code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to put the zoom effect on my `ImageView`. and when I wrote
`android: scaleType = "matrix"` on my XML code, the image expands and is not seen in full on the layout how to avoid this?
with large images.

Comment: use Matrix#setRectToRect for example

Comment: please I do not understand you I am a beginner in programming I use Matrix # setRectToRect how? explain me please @pskink

Comment: what's unclear with setRectToRect? did you try that at least?

Comment: I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO

Comment: so what did you try? what is your code using setRectToRect?